# What should I use for text to speech?

Tags: c++, speech-synthesis

I am trying to create a spelling program that reads a word to the user and checks the word they input. What should I use for the text-to-speech part? Or should I use prerecorded words instead of real-time text to speech. The program will be written in c++. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Words prerecorded using the Opus codec don't take much size, but it's more flexible to use a text-to-speech library. Windows and MacOS have those preinstalled; just search for "OS speech API C++".